# Class and instance variable naming suggestions for a class monitoring a file directory which deletes files when a maximum size has been exceeded

Tags: java

I'm struggling with an appropriate class name and an instance variable name for the class depicted below:

[image: class UML diagram]

The class is instantiated with a maximum and minimum size (in bytes) and a `File` object representing a directory to monitor. A `WatchService` is created to file creation events in the directory.

The run method runs an infinite loop fetching watch events from the watch service.   When processing each event, if the directory size is found to exceed `maxDirectorySize` files are deleted until the directory size falls below `cleanedDirectorySize`.

Can someone suggest:

1. an appropriate class name? `DirectorySizeMonitorAndCleanerTask` is the best I could come up with and I still don't like it
2. a better name for `cleanedDirectorySize` that better represents the variable's intent?

Comment: Please let me know if this class of questions is inappropriate for SO, but in my experience, I have spent an unjustifiably large portion of my professional career mulling over appropriate variable names...

Comment: This seems like _a good question_ but one that would be better suited for one of the other code-related SE sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion

```
 DirectoryCapacityWatcher {

      long capacityLowWatermark;
      long capacityHighWatermark;
      ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason why you're struggling to find a good class name is that you're breaking a SOLID principle, single responsibility. It's difficult to name a task that has two or more responsibilities.

You could instead consider having a DirectoryService class that uses the locator pattern or dependency injection pattern and compose that class of DirectorySizeMonitor and DirectoryCleanerTask. That service could then have the single responsibility of determining when to monitor and when to clean, but have no idea how to do either.

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate name for the class would be I think
`TaskSupervisor`

Answer (score 0):

How about `DirectoryJanitor`, `startCleaningAbove` and `stopCleaningBelow`?